# Where is the documentation for _()?

Tags: php, documentation

I tried to create a new function and call it _(), but it turns out there already is one. However, i'm unable to find any documentation about it since it's not in the list of magic methods, Google ignores my bracket/underscore combination, php.net returns nothing, trying to guess `http://www.php.net/manual/en/function._.php` didn't work...

Does it have a name? How do i find it?

Comment: This link works: http://www.php.net/_ (`You may use the underscore character '_' as an alias to this function.`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the [`gettext()`](http://www.php.net/_) function.